# Limsup of random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, limsup-and-liminf

Let $X_n$ be a non-negative decreasing sequence of random variables i.e. $X_n < X_{n-1}$  for $n\in\{1,2,...,\}$ such that $\mathbb P[0\le X_0<\infty] = 1$.

Is $\sup\mathbb E[X_n]<\infty$ ?

Is the supremum finite when $\mathbb E[X_0]<\infty$?
$(n\in \mathbb N\cup\{0\})$

I think that I should try to use the monotony of $E$ but I don't know how to start the proof.

Comment: I think that i should try to use the monotony property of E but i don't know how to start the proof.

Comment: Are you assuming that they are non-negative?

Comment: Yes, they are non-negative, decreasing and n belong natural numbers union zero

Comment: Do you also want to know whether the expecation is finite? Because as written now it is always true.

Comment: yes you are right, i just fixed it, must be finite, stricly less than infinity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\{X_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ are non-negative and decreasing, then monotonicity gives us that:

$\mathbb{E}[X_n]\leq \mathbb{E}[X_0]$ for all $n$, and if $\mathbb{E}[X_0]<\infty$, then $\sup \mathbb{E}[X_n]<\infty$. If however $\mathbb{E}[X_0]=\infty$, I think the following counter-example shows this need not be the case:

$\Omega=[0,1]$ and $X_0(\omega)=2^{m+3}$ for $\omega\in \Big[ \sum\limits_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{2^k},\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m+1} \frac{1}{2^k} \Big]$ with $\mathbb{P}\Bigg( \Big[ \sum\limits_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{2^k},\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m+1} \frac{1}{2^k} \Big]\Bigg)=\frac{1}{2^{m+1}}$. And define:
 $X_n(\omega)=2^{m+2}+\frac{1}{n}$ for $\omega\in \Big[ \sum\limits_{k=1}^m \frac{1} {2^k},\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m+1} \frac{1}{2^k} \Big]$, with $\mathbb{P}\Bigg( \Big[ \sum\limits_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{2^k},\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m+1} \frac{1}{2^k} \Big]\Bigg)=\frac{1}{2^{m+1}}$. Then they all have infinite expectation, and $\sup \mathbb{E}[X_n]=\infty$.